# Organizing Test Names in MSTest

Tags: unit-testing, naming-conventions, mstest

I'm using MSTest and I find myself writing some rather ridiculous test method names so I can have some idea of what's running when I look at my test results.

In order to make sense of what's what in the test explorer's results list, I wind up using almost a "namespace-inclusive" method name.  The straw that broke my back?  `PostImportMemberStagingBeginImportThrowsArgOutOfRangeIfImportMethodUnrecognized()`

[image]

Note the `GetImportReturnsImportView` method in the image.  I'll have to change this name at some point because it'll probably wind up being near-duplicated, and it doesn't really tell me what it's testing.

In the MSTest window, I could sort by Class, but that doesn't really do much (and I'd much rather view by test project anyway).  Ideally would be some sort of full tree results so I could drill in by namespace/test class.

What sort of test naming conventions can I use to achieve something fairly reasonable to quickly review in the test results, without having to go crazy with method names?

I'm trying to avoid external tools (I already use OpenCover and ReportGenerator externally for integration level stuff, so this is really just for quick in-VS reference)

Comment: Try using the "group by" on the test explorer, I like to group by class.  Though, I find ReSharper's test runner to organize the tests much better than the built in test runner

Comment: Oh, looking at your image again, I guess you might already be doing that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the TestCategory attribute at the class/assembly level. MSTest supports this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/02/25/mstest-v2-now-and-ahead/
Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks

Comment: This is 404 now , can you edit your answer and add it here

Comment: Still 404. This isn't archived in the wayback machine either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`TestCategory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx) attribute to better organize tests into modules. Beside that, I find naming tests in `Given..._When..._Then...` format, which corresponds to test body very convenient:

```cs
public class EditControllerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Controller tests")]
    public void GivenSomething_WhenSomethingHappens_ThenResultIsSomething()
    {
        GivenSomeData(new Data() { X = 1, Y = 2 });

        WhenControllerActionExecutes(editController.Index);

        Assert.Equals(jsonResult, "...");
    }
}
```

And of course, what's best, is to abandon MSTest and use something more mature, like NUnit (conversion from one to another is easy to perform automatically). NUnit has categories for classes.

Comment: Thanks, didn't really want to use that though... I already do for Integration testing, and while we can use multiples on a method, it's a lot of extra typing and clutter for something that I was hoping MSTest would be able to resolve on it's own.  (if we could apply that to a test class, I'd be much more apt to use it for this!)